# How can I debug my flask app when it wont run?

Tags: python, flask, localhost, virtualenv

I've been developing my flask app locally for a while and I've had no problems. I am currently working in a virtual environment. Now when I try to start my flask app, it times out and won't load.

```
python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
```

Nothing else happens after this. If I edit my code in my text editor and save it, the debugger recognizes it by displaying this.

```
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
```

I've had this running uninterrupted for 5 minutes and nothing happens. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and reinstall your virtual environment. That may "flush" some errors.

Also, is your app running in debug mode? It should be if you're developing locally. The following should be at the bottom of your code.

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Please let me know if that works, otherwise i'll keep searching for you.

Comment: I have that at the bottom of my code but I get the same results

Comment: Do what Dave said and show us more of your code. Also, did you reinstall your virtual environment?

Comment: it does not work in my case as well. reinstalling does not change anything.